# PIVOT table in SAP HANA STUDIO

Tags: pivot, hana

I write this sql

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT ATNAM, ausp.objek, ATWRT 
    from saphanadb.ausp 
    inner join saphanadb.cabn 
    on ausp.mandt=cabn.mandt 
    and ausp.atinn=cabn.atinn 
    where ausp.mandt=300 and klart='ZCV' 
    ) AS MyPivotSourceData
    PIVOT ( 
        MAX(ATWRT) 
        FOR ATNAM IN ('CK', 'WH', 'HP', 'OTHER')    
   ) AS MyPivotedData
ORDER BY ausp.objek
```

I got this message

Could not execute 'SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ATNAM, ausp.objek, ATWRT from saphanadb.ausp inner join saphanadb.cabn on ...'

SAP DBTech JDBC: [257]: sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "PIVOT": line 10 col 4 (at pos 243)

what is the Problem ???

I search without any result

Answer (score 0):

It's literally what it says: The syntax is incorrect as there is no `PIVOT` keyword in SAP HANA. When doing a [documentation search](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database?q=pivot) you will recognise that there are no relevant results.

Comment: What about this

https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SQL_Anywhere/93079d4ba8e44920ae63ffb4def91f5b/817234f06ce210149f3fe4ad7428edfd.html?locale=en-US

Comment: @DoubleClick SAP offers more than one database product. Your link is referring to the documentation of "SAP SQL Anywhere", which is a different database than SAP HANA. From your chosen tags, I was anticipating that your question refers to SAP HANA, which does not support the `PIVOT` clause. Please clarify and adjust the tags if this is not the case.